# Think I have a dead starter?

Tags: starter

I tried to start up my car today and there is silence when I try to start the ignition. Lights, are strong and Vent Fan and radio all work well too so I'm trying to rule out a dead battery. Would this then be the starter?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the voltage at the battery without the ignition on?

Comment: Have you tried to get a jump start, It may be possible for the battery to have some juice to power the lights and fan but not enough to power the starter. If you can charge the battery or try to jump start it you can see if the problem is still there when you know the battery is fully charged.

Comment: Unusual , but there could be a problem in the ignition/key cylinder.

Comment: If you hear not even a klick when you try to start (have someone listen in the engine bay) I would also bet on ignition or starter relay (or even broken cable connection)